# Golang return nil

Tags: go, revel

I am trying to wrap my head around Golang's types and interfaces but am struggling a bit to do so.  Anyways, a common pattern that I see is `func Whatever() (thing string, err error)`.  I get how all of that works, but the one thing I am confused on is why it is ok to `return "thing", nil`.  The specific instance that I am looking at is in revel here-

```
func (c *GorpController) Begin() revel.Result {
    txn, err := Dbm.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c.Txn = txn
    return nil
}
```

`revel.Result` is an interface with this signature-

```
type Result interface {
    Apply(req *Request, resp *Response)
}
```

Anyways, I am just curious how returning `nil` satisfies the compiler in that occasion.  Is there a resource that I can be pointed to for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is similar to returning a nil error: see "[Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) "

> Under the covers, **interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type and a value**.
>
> The value, called the interface's dynamic value, is an arbitrary concrete value and the type is that of the value. For the `int` value `3`, an interface value contains, schematically, (`int, 3`).
>
> An interface value is `nil` only if the inner value and type are both unset, (`nil, nil`). In particular, a `nil` interface will always hold a `nil` type.
> If we store a pointer of type `*int` inside an interface value, the inner type will be `*int` regardless of the value of the pointer: (`*int, nil`).
> Such an interface value will therefore be `non-nil` even when the pointer inside is `nil`.

Here `nil` is the zero-value of the interface `revel.Result`.

Comment: Perfect explanation.  Thanks so much for that.  Go is one of those languages that is simultaneously the easiest and more difficult languages that I have ever learned.